# How to select email from a particular sender? (IMAPLIB)

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, imaplib

I want to select emails from a particular sender,`a@gmail.com` in Inbox

```
gmail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
gmail.login(gmail_username,gmail_password)
gmail.select('Inbox', readonly=True)
```

Comment: always search by [ **specific** sender] instead [ **particular** sender] keyword:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944727/python-imaplib-view-message-to-specific-sender

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search) method instead:

```
gmail.search(None, 'FROM', 'a@gmail.com')
```